# NoSuchElementException when reading a file

Tags: java

When I run this code the console throws a NoSuchElementException. Why is that? Isn't the file being opened? The error says it corresponds to the line 34. Why?
 Is Scanner reading the input from the file? Please help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class standardDeviation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File myFile = new File("input_data.txt");

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(myFile);
    output.print("78.76 96.7 65.65 95.64 68.5 6.54 54.6");
    output.close();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
    String fileName = input.nextLine();

    double sd = deviation(myFile);
    System.out.println("The standard deviation of the values in this file is: " + sd);

    }

public static double deviation(File myFile) throws FileNotFoundException{   

    Scanner in = new Scanner(myFile);

    int i = 0; 
    double sum = 0;
    double sigmaXI2 = 0;
    while(i != -1){
        double num = in.nextDouble();
        sum += num;
        sigmaXI2 += Math.pow(num, 2);
        i++;
    }
    double sigmaXI_2 = Math.pow(sum, 2);
    double s = Math.sqrt((sigmaXI2 - (sigmaXI_2)/i)/(i-1));



    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: your while loop is never ending. try this: while (in.hasNext())

Answer (score 0):

When do you expect the end of loop?

```
 while(i != -1)
```

i keeps increasing and no there is no break.

According to JavaDoc of Scanner.nextDouble()

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw
> InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
> valid double value. If the translation is successful, the scanner
> advances past the input that matched.
>
> If the next token matches the Float regular expression defined above
> then the token is converted into a double value as if by removing all
> locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific
> suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via
> Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific
> negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting
> string to Double.parseDouble. If the token matches the localized NaN
> or infinity strings, then either "Nan" or "Infinity" is passed to
> Double.parseDouble as appropriate. Returns:the double scanned from the
> input Throws: InputMismatchException - if the next token does not
> match the Float regular expression, or is out of range
>
> **NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted**
>
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

When all token is exhausted due to infinite loop,  NoSuchElementException is thrown.
To solve the problem, use hasNextDouble() method as the checking condition.